# Elimination of variables from a system of equation.

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions

Suppose $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$ are real numbers. Consider the system of equation
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
a + bx  + cy \\ \frac{d}{x} + e + fz \\ \frac{g}{y} + \frac{h}{z} + i
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
We need to eliminate the variables $x,y$ and $z$ from the above (assuming that solution for the variables $x,y$ and $z$ exists) and get a single  equation in $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$. I do not know it is possible or not. I hope this is possible but I am unable to get the required. Any suggestion or further help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a single equation" in $a,b,...,i$? A polynomial equation $f(a, b,...,i)=0$ with $f$ not the zero polynomial?

Comment: Exactly, @DietrichBurde.

Comment: Then my answer shows that we need not obtain such an equation (but we can, e.g., for the $2\times 2$-analogue you gave earlier).

Answer (score -1):

Multiplying by $x,y,z$ we obtain three polynomial equations in $x,y,z$. Taking resultants we can solve it. The formulas, however, are rather complicated. To show an easy example, take the case of $b=0$. Then we obtain
$$
y=\frac{1-a}{c},\quad z=\frac{h( 1- a )}{ai - a - cg - i + 1}
$$
and
$$
x=\frac{d( - ai + a + cg + i - 1)}{aei - ae - afh - ai + a - ceg + cg -  ei + e + fh + i - 1}.
$$
This example also shows that the coefficients $a,b,\cdots ,i$ need not satisfy a nontrivial polynomial equation in general. In fact, all coefficients are arbitrary in the above formula except for the denominators being nonzero.

Comment: Why must $b=0$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I did not say that $b$ must be zero. I said, to see a formula in an example, let's take $b=0$. The general formula is too long.

Comment: And what would you do if $b\ne 0$?

Comment: This is not an elimination.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is not an elimination?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: your answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I haven't written down here the elimination in general, because it is ugly. But it is possible (but involves solving quadratic equations, i.e., contains square roots in terms of polynomials in the coefficients). I said this clearly.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: it is not possible, there are not enough equations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, there is a solution of the form $x=(sqrt(f)+ g)/h$ and likewise for $y,z$, where $f,g,h$ are polynomials in $a,b,...,i$. I have verified it with the computer, that they are valid.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: this is *not* an elimination. This is *not* what the OP asks.

Comment: It is a formula for an explicit solution for $x,y,z$ in terms of the coefficients, hence an "elimination" for a system of polynomial equations. What definition do you have? Is it the one the OP wanted? He did not specify this. Actually, the OP wanted an equation in the coefficients only. Is this the reason of your downvoting?

Answer (score -1):

If the solution for the variables $x,y$ and $z$ exist and you're given this:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a + bx  + cy \\ \frac{d}{x} + e + fz \\ \frac{g}{y} + \frac{h}{z} + i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and then you're asked to find one single equation for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ and $i$, then you can add up the components and get your desired one single equation like so:
$$3 = a + bx  + cy + \frac{d}{x} + e + fz + \frac{g}{y} + \frac{h}{z} + i$$

You're welcome.

***EDIT***

Okay, now I get it, you want to elimnate the variables $x,y,z$. Never mind, if $x,y,z$ are known or not.

This is a different question!!!

Fine, a good way is to do it like Dr. Sonnhard Graubner already described. Solve the first equation for $y$ and you get

$$y = y(x) = 1/c - a/c - (b/c)x$$

Then solve the second equation for $z$ and you get

$$ z = z(x) = 1/f - e/f - d/(fx) $$

Now plug $y=y(x)$ and $z=z(x)$ in the third equation and you get

$$ 1 = g/(1/c - a/c - (b/c)x) + h/(1/f - e/f - d/(fx)) + i $$

or also (just differently written)

$$ 1 = gc(1 - a - bx)^{-1} + hf(1- e - dx^{-1})^{-1} + i $$

If we solve this last equation for $x$ ("the only unknown"), then we're done, because you can plug that $x$ in $y(x)$ and in $z(x)$ and get all $x,y$ and $z$ in terms of the other variables. It can be solved, but it's not handy. Maybe there's a crazy trick, that will help to solve it without much struggle? I will think about it. If I find something, then I will let you know.

Comment: The equation should be in the coefficients only (see remark by OP). This is not the case here, since $x,y,z$ are still there.

Comment: Right, got that!